# Accidentally locked phpmyadmin localhost

Tags: phpmyadmin

In the process of trying to set up my database on phpmyadmin to have a password, I was locking things (stupidly) and accidentally **locked the localhost access**.

[image: error]

I've tried:

- Changing the user, password, & port in MySQL config `my.ini`.
- Changing the user & password in PHPMyAdmin config `config.inc.php` & changing the port from `3306` -> `4306`.

> ```php
> /* Authentication type and info */
> $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
> $cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'USER';
> $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'PASS';
> $cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
> $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
> $cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = 4306;
> $cfg['Lang'] = '';
> ```
>
> **Note:** even when changing to `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;` it still doesn't work.

> **Note #2:** when changing to `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';` I get [this error](https://i.gyazo.com/f27cc81470ab4da17efdc85ff6bed65e.png) on the login page.

- `mysql -p -u root` & `mysql -p -u USER` but get this error when entering the right credentials:

> ```
> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
> ```

- Looked at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4530862/added-password-to-root-locked-out-of-phpmyadmin) but this still didn't work for me.
- Tried `mysql stop` but get this error (based on looking at [this thread](https://www.daniweb.com/programming/web-development/threads/501441/locked-out-of-phpmyadmin)):

> ```
> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'MYNAME'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
> ```

- It seems the only thread I could find with someone who's seemingly done the exact same thing as me is [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/1722732/phpmyadmin-access-denied-due-to-accidentally-lock-account).

So, I've come the conclusion there is *something* I need to do in order to unlock accessing phpmyadmin via localhost, but I have no idea what. I don't think the problem is relating to an invalid password or username but instead just localhost being "locked".

**How do I unlock it?**

Comment: the port is wrong(not standard ) if you didn't set it on purpose on mysql server . that should be 3306 ;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I faced the same issue**, and I resolved it in the following way.

I faced this issue on a XAMPP server, and I opened up the XAMPP server and restarted all of the services. *Then stopped all of the services and started again.*

That lock option in phpmyadmin is basically to lock users out for that particular session, which means whenever you restart, everything will reconfigure in case you locked yourself out.

Comment: this won't work with Wamp server

Answer (score 1):

Try to bring down your mysql instance, followed by

```bash
mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
```

then make your changes, like changing the password or the access limitation.
Example:

```sql
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'NewPassword';
```

After that, flush the privileges and restart mysql.

Answer (score 0):

I just uninstalled and re-installed xampp and that did it. Just have to re-set up my database